# Multiple Alignment in equations

Tags: equations, align

The following equations need to be aligned in two spots. If I use the align* environment then the second column of alignment is pushed to the right edge of the page. I googled this and saw that alignat* was suggested. So I tried that, and now the numbers aren't aligned where the alignment symbol is. How should I align the following properly,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    S(1)&=(1.05)S(0)=(1.05)(50000)&=52500\\
    S(2)&=(1.05)S(1)=(1.05)(52500)&=55125\\
    S(3)&=(1.05)S(2)=(1.05)(55125)&=57881.25\\
    S(4)&=(1.05)S(3)=(1.05)(57881.25)&\approx60775.31\\
    S(5)&=(1.05)S(4)\approx(1.05)(60775.31)&\approx63814.08\\
    S(6)&=(1.05)S(5)\approx(1.05)(63814.08)&\approx67004.78\\
    S(7)&=(1.05)S(6)\approx(1.05)(67004.78)&\approx70355.02\\
    S(8)&=(1.05)S(7)\approx(1.05)(70355.02)&\approx73872.77
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
Here is an image of what I want. I created it using the same code but using spaces to align the equals signs.

[image: Example]

Comment: I like this question: in addition to the author having done their homework first, it's also about a somewhat obscure and difficult construction that needs some airing out.

Comment: Please clarify your question with an image of what you want (a few minutes to mock something up in whatever simple graphics package comes with your system will be fine) and upgrade your code snippet to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/9043) to allow people to copy, paste and experiment.

Comment: While I still believe my question was clear (the use of the words "aligned in two spots" along with two alignment symbols in the code), I have added the image and updated the code.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`alignat` alternates between right and left column alignment. So, you need to add an additional column to ensure that the last one is left aligned.

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    S(1)&=(1.05)S(0)=(1.05)(50000)         &&=2500\\
    S(2)&=(1.05)S(1)=(1.05)(52500)         &&=5125\\
    S(3)&=(1.05)S(2)=(1.05)(55125)         &&=7881.25\\
    S(4)&=(1.05)S(3)=(1.05)(57881.25)      &&\approx60775.31\\
    S(5)&=(1.05)S(4)\approx(1.05)(60775.31)&&\approx63814.08\\
    S(6)&=(1.05)S(5)\approx(1.05)(63814.08)&&\approx67004.78\\
    S(7)&=(1.05)S(6)\approx(1.05)(67004.78)&&\approx70355.02\\
    S(8)&=(1.05)S(7)\approx(1.05)(70355.02)&&\approx73872.77
\end{alignat*}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely, but I have to add a space after the last & symbol when I use this method, as the alignment removes it for some reason. Not a big deal though, and thanks for the explanation as well.

Comment: The equality symbols in the final column are a little close to the numbers. Could you put at little padding in?

Comment: It would probably work better with `&&=` in place of `&=&`, because of this issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41091/575.