# Align some equations in empheq environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, empheq

I am trying to align some equations in an empheq environment but cannot get it right. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\integers}[2]{[\![#1,#2]\!]}

\begin{document}

Test 1:
\begin{empheq}{align}
&\max~w_1 \sum_{i,j} t_{ij}(1-x_{ij})+w_2 gl\sum_{i,j} \Big(4x_{ij}-\sum_{(p,q)\in A_{ij}} z_{ijpq}\Big)&&\\
& z_{ijpq} \leq y_i &\forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& z_{ijpq} \leq y_j &\forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& z_{ijpq} \geq y_i + y_j - 1 &\forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}&\forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& z_{ijpq} \in \{0,1\}&\forall i,p \in \integers{1}{m}, \forall j,q \in \integers{1}{n}
\end{empheq}

Test 2:

\begin{empheq}{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}


\end{document}
```

Test2 comes from the `empheq` documentation. **Here are my two questions:**

1. Test2 is aligned left, as expected, but Test1 is not. How can I align all left in Test1?

[image: Wrong alignment]

2. The first equation of Test1 being very long, I would like to ignore it in the `align`, and get something like this (the green lines show the alignment I am looking for):

[image: Targeted alignment]

I tried something which does not compile:

```
\begin{empheq}[left=(P_2)\empheqlbrace]
\max~w_1 \sum_{i,j} t_{ij}(1-x_{ij})+w_2 gl\sum_{i,j} x_{ij}\Big(4-\sum_{(p,q)\in A_{ij}} x_{pq}\Big)\\
\begin{align*}
& x_{ij} \in \{0,1\} &forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}
\end{align*}
\end{empheq}
```

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137041/how-to-align-only-some-equations-in-an-align-environment) on StackExchange but I couldn't make it work with `empheq`.

Comment: Why using `empheq` for this?

Comment: I am using `empheq` because in fact I use it with `[left=\empheqlbrace]` option, since it is a system of equations. You're right to ask because I forgot to add this option in the MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with use of `alignat=3` you can obtain:

[image]

**edit** as noted [barbara beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) in her comment below (thank you very much!), if really want to left-align the column on the right, you should use `&&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\integers}[2]{[\![#1,#2]\!]}

\begin{document}

Test 1:
\begin{empheq}{alignat=3} % <---
& \max~w_1 \sum_{i,j} t_{ij}(1-x_{ij})
                        && + w_2 gl\sum_{i,j} \Big(4x_{ij}-\sum_{(p,q)\in A_{ij}} z_{ijpq}\Big)\\
& z_{ijpq} \leq y_i     &&   \forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& z_{ijpq} \leq y_j     &&   \forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& z_{ijpq} \geq y_i + y_j - 1
                        &&   \forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}    &&   \forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& z_{ijpq} \in \{0,1\}  &&   \forall i,p \in \integers{1}{m}, \forall j,q \in \integers{1}{n}
\end{empheq}

Test 2:

\begin{empheq}{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

The very same result can be obtain without use of `empheq` environment:

```
\begin{alignat}{3} % <---
& \max~w_1 \sum_{i,j} t_{ij}(1-x_{ij})
                        && + w_2 gl\sum_{i,j} \Big(4x_{ij}-\sum_{(p,q)\in A_{ij}} z_{ijpq}\Big)\\
& z_{ijpq} \leq y_i     &&   \forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& z_{ijpq} \leq y_j     &&   \forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& z_{ijpq} \geq y_i + y_j - 1
                        &&   \forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}    &&   \forall i \in \integers{1}{m}, j \in \integers{1}{n}\\
& z_{ijpq} \in \{0,1\}  &&   \forall i,p \in \integers{1}{m}, \forall j,q \in \integers{1}{n}
\end{alignat}

Test 2:
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{align}
```

Comment: you really want to left-align the column on the right.  (use `&&`)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you very much! i corrected the answer.

Comment: @egreg, ups, `+` was on wrong side of ampersands :-(. now corrected. also helps your suggestion, of course. thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect! I don't really understand why it works though: since there are 3 columns, the third column (after the `&&`) should start at the end of the long first equation, no?

Comment: @fidekild, no. it start at anchor `&&` which is before sign `+` after first term.

Comment: Ok I missed this sign in the first equation. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Using the `alignat` and `align` environments, respectively, yealds the same result. What is the need for `empheq`?

Comment: @JoãoBravo, of course, however, OP use `empheq` in her/his MWE, so I left  it. I will add comment to my answer asap.