# Equations with several identities

Tags: equations

I want to write a simple single line equation of this kind: `a = b + c = d + e + f`. However, when I try to add the second identity ( = ), everything on its right side does not appear in the results. Following a piece of code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43464/multiple-alignment-in-equations) I used the `&=` for either the second identity or both the first and the second. Still I am doing something wrong. 
Here follows the code I am trying to use

```
\begin{equation}
\hat{{\varphi}_{it} (i_{it}, k_{it})} &= \hat{y_{it}} - \hat{{\beta}_{l}} l_{it} - \hat{{\vartheta}_{1}} X_{it} - \hat{{\vartheta}_{2}} Z_{it} &= \hat{{delta_{0}} + \sum{\sum{{\delta}_{ij} k_{t}^{i} i_{t}^{j}}} - \hat{{\beta}_{l}}l_{it} - \hat{{\vartheta}_{1}} X_{it} - \hat{{\vartheta}_{2}} Z_{it}
\end{equation}
```

I get the 3 following error messages exactly, attributed to the line after the command `\end{equation}`:

```
 Paragraph ended before \mathaccent\/ was complete
 Missing $ inserted
 Display math should end with $$
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please try to give the minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)) in which your problem occurs. Creating it is the first step in debugging and helps us tremendously in pin-pointing where the issue may lie. In particular it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: remove the `&` (equation is not an alignment environment)

Comment: Suggestion: when you have a _long_ equation to write, do it a little bit at a time and compile each time. Then it will be easier to locate errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you try to obtain? The first approach is a pure/simple math environment, the second is use of `array` environment, and the third approach is use of `align` environment. This solution simplifies the code.

Note: There was an extra `\hat` on the second equation right after = without an ending `}` and was removed. Also a backslash was missing for `delta` in the second equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% -- case 1

\begin{equation}
%\begin{array}{lll}
\hat{\varphi}_{it} (i_{it}, k_{it}) =\hat{y}_{it} - \hat{\beta_l} l_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_1 X_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_2 Z_{it} \\
= \delta_0+ \sum{\sum{\delta_{ij} k_{t}^{i} i_{t}^{j}}} - \hat{\beta_l} l_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_{1} X_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_{2} Z_{it}
%\end{array}
\end{equation}
\vspace{1cm}

% -- case 2

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lll}
\hat{\varphi}_{it} (i_{it}, k_{it}) &=\hat{y}_{it} - \hat{\beta_l} l_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_1 X_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_2 Z_{it} \\
&= \delta_0+ \sum{\sum{\delta_{ij} k_{t}^{i} i_{t}^{j}}} - \hat{\beta_l} l_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_{1} X_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_{2} Z_{it}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\vspace{1cm}

% --- case 3

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\varphi}_{it} (i_{it}, k_{it}) &= \hat{y}_{it} - \hat{\beta_l} l_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_1 X_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_2 Z_{it} \\
&= \delta_0+ \sum{\sum{\delta_{ij} k_{t}^{i} i_{t}^{j}}} - \hat{\beta_l} l_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_{1} X_{it} - \hat{\vartheta}_{2} Z_{it}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. What am I instead supposed to do if I want to put everything on the same line ?

Comment: OK just remove the \\ on the first line and remove the second &. You will get a one line equation. But it may exceed the text width.

Comment: Of course you could remove the array environment in the first case, for example, and all the & out of the equation and still get a one line equation.

Comment: Yes, in equation environment & does not work and shows error. But the \\ (if any) does not work either, all will continue to be typeset.