# Special column separator in first line

Tags: tables, symbols

I need to reproduce the following table using LaTeX.

[image: Needed LaTeX table]

I've tried to use a custom column separator, like `@{$\oplus$}`, but it affect every line of the table and that is not what I need.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c@{+}c@{=}c@{+}c@{=}c@{+}c@{+}c|}
    \hline
    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
    \hline
    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I would like to be able to use a math symbol in place of `+` or `=`, like `\oplus`.

Comment: You may be looking for `align`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations -- or `alignat`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43464/multiple-alignment-in-equations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
    \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c!{\makebox[0pt]{$+$}}}{cell}&
  \multicolumn{1}{c!{\makebox[0pt]{$=$}}}{cell}&
  \multicolumn{1}{c!{\makebox[0pt]{$+$}}}{cell}&
  \multicolumn{1}{c!{\makebox[0pt]{$=$}}}{cell}&
  \multicolumn{1}{c!{\makebox[0pt]{$+$}}}{cell}&
  \multicolumn{1}{c!{\makebox[0pt]{$+$}}}{cell}&
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{cell}\\
    \hline
    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Subsidiary question: What is the purpose of the `\makebox[0pt]` command?

Comment: @TomBarthe try it without:-) the content of `!` (or `@`)  is at the right hand edge of the previous cell, so if you just did `+` it would look as if it was to the left of the vertical rule below. `\makebox` forces it to have zero width overprinting the cell padding on either side so it sits over the `|` (but put in `++++++` and it will overprint the cell contents with no warning unless you increase `\tabcolsep` to leave more room.

Answer (score 1):

The first table is cleaner, the second table is with the obnoxious vertical rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c *{6}{@{$\mskip\thickmuskip$}c@{$\mskip\thickmuskip$}c} }
\toprule
cell & $+$ & cell & $=$ & cell & $+$ & cell & $=$ & cell & $+$ & cell & $+$ & cell \\
\midrule
cell && cell && cell && cell && cell && cell && cell \\
cell && cell && cell && cell && cell && cell && cell \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ |c *{6}{@{$\mskip\thickmuskip$}c@{$\mskip\thickmuskip$}c}| }
\hline
cell & $+$ & cell & $=$ & cell & $+$ & cell & $=$ & cell & $+$ & cell & $+$ & cell \\
\hline
cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell \\
\hline
cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell &\vline& cell \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]