# How to type equations inside a box more compactly?

Tags: align, texmaker, empheq

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=.2in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{empheq}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
    \sin 2A&=2\sin A\cos A=\frac{2\tan A}{1+\tan^2 A}\\
    \cos 2A&=\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A=2\cos^2 A-1=1-2\sin^2 A=\frac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}\\
    2\cos^2 A&=1+\cos2A\\
    2\sin^2 A&=1-\cos2A\\
    \tan^2 A&=\frac{1-\cos2A}{1+\cos2A}
    \end{empheq}
    \end{document}
```

I have just started using latex. This displays the following set of formulas: [image]I want to utilize the blank space inside the box. If I were to add a few more formulas, how would I do that?

Comment: as always on this site, please post full (but minimal) self contained examples, not smiplets. When there are documentclass and preamble it ius easier to test and people are more incliened to help. For example the first image does not come from the code you provide (the first tan is a giveaway)

Comment: @daleif I have edited the post. Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to align all equals signs on the left of the box; the last formula for the tangent can be to the right of the corresponding formulas for sine and cosine.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.2in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
& \begin{aligned}
  \sin 2A&=2\sin A\cos A=\frac{2\tan A}{1+\tan^2 A}\\
  \cos 2A&=\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A=2\cos^2 A-1=1-2\sin^2 A=\frac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}
  \end{aligned}
\\[2ex]
& \begin{aligned}
  2\cos^2 A&=1+\cos2A\\
  2\sin^2 A&=1-\cos2A
  \end{aligned}
  \hspace{4em}
  \tan^2 A=\frac{1-\cos2A}{1+\cos2A}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Plus you can save estra space if you smash the fraction is the second line

Comment: @daleif I added vertical space to avoid it being too compact and clearly separate the two halves.

Comment: @egreg exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @egregyes after, but you can save space above and get more or less the same spacing between the 3th and 4th line.

Answer (score 0):

The `align*` environment (which is really what's displaying these equations, inside the `empheq` environment) allows you to have more than one column of equations. For example:

```
\begin{align*}
a&=b         &      c&=d\\
e&=f         &      g&=h
\end{align*}
```

will produce two columns, with "a=b" and "e=f" in the left column (aligned on the euqals sign), and "c=d" and "g=h" in the right column. It's possible to use more alignment characters (`&`) to create more columns, too. See e.g. [Multiple Alignment in equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43464/multiple-alignment-in-equations) for more info.

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.2in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\sin 2A&=2\sin A\cos A=\frac{2\tan A}{1+\tan^2 A}
    &  \tan^2 A&=\frac{1-\cos2A}{1+\cos2A}\\
\cos 2A&=\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A=2\cos^2 A-1
    &  2\sin^2 A&=1-\cos2A\\
&=1-2\sin^2 A=\frac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}
    &  2\cos^2 A&=1+\cos2A
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Note that I broke up the long line for `\cos 2A` as the alignment wouldn't have done a very nice job on this otherwise. The result is this:

[image: Align* environment with two columns]