# Aligning relatively positioned nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]
    \tikzstyle{apr}=[rectangle,
                     align=center,
                     text width = 3cm,
                     node distance = 1cm,
                     rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
                     draw, fill=white]

    \node(1) [apr]
        {
        \textbf{Lore Ipsum}\\ \textbf{Dolor}
        \nodepart{second} {$
                          \begin{aligned}
                          x = &\: 10 \\
                          y = &\: 20 \\
                          \dot{x} = &\: 0
                          \end{aligned}
                          $}
        };
    \node(4) [apr, right = of 1]
        {
        \textbf{Lore Ipsum}\\ \textbf{Stupid Descenders}
        \nodepart{second} {$
                          \begin{aligned}
                          x = &\: 10 \\
                          \dot{x} = &\: 0
                          \end{aligned}
                          $}
        };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the tops of the nodes align instead of their centers?

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `\node (4) [apr, right = of 1.base east, anchor=base west]` could be one way, or `north` instead of `base`.

Comment: And not related to TikZ, but the correct use of `amsmath` align environments is `& =` instead of spacing tricks like `= & \:`. See [Relation spacing error using =& in aligned equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41074)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Result]

Use appropiate `anchor` in the relatively positioned node, and specify the appropiate corner in the `right = of ...` option:

```
[...]
\node(4) [apr, right  = of 1.north east, anchor=north west]
[...]
```

Comment: Note that the order here is important. `right = of ...` sets the `anchor` to `west` so you need to override it by setting `anchor=north west` afterwards.  Putting `anchor=north west` before `right=of ...` has no effect.