# Horizontal alignment across nested aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Is there a way to left align the first 2 rows with the last one?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{equation*}
\left\{{\begin{aligned}
&\left.{\begin{aligned}
&A+B=X\\
&B+C=Y\end{aligned}}\right\}2A+B+C=X+Z\\
&C+A=Z
\end{aligned}}\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left.\smash{\raisebox{-.7\baselineskip}{$\left\{\begin{aligned}
A+B&=X\\
B+C&=Y\\
C+A&=Z
\end{aligned}\right.$}}
\rule{0pt}{1.3\baselineskip}
\right\}
2A+B+C=X+Z
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see @egreg beat me to it, this has a bit more handwork getting the vertical spacing right but has full alignment on the three `=` rather than relying on `A` `B` and `C` being similar width.

Answer (score 4):

There are three spaces you don't take into account.

1. A `\left...\right` construction has a thin space before and after it;
2. An empty delimiter produces a space as wide as `\nulldelimiterspace`;
3. `aligned` has a thin space before it (see [Why is there a \, space at the beginning of the "aligned" environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/why-is-there-a-space-at-the-beginning-of-the-aligned-environment)).

Here's how remove those spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{0pt} % locally set the added space to zero
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\!\left.\!\begin{aligned}
&A+B=X\\
&B+C=Y\end{aligned}\right\}2A+B+C=X+Z\\
&C+A=Z
\end{aligned}\right.\!
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]