# How to remove the unwanted space on the left side of the following gather*?

Tags: spacing, amsmath, standalone

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{gather*}
6x^2-30x+36=0\\
6(x^2-5x+6)=0\\
6(x-2)(x-3)=0\\
x-2=0 \quad \text{or} \quad x-3=0\\
x=2 \quad \text{or} \quad x=3
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Is it [a bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfwuK.png)?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/why-is-there-a-space-at-the-beginning-of-the-aligned-environment/103858#103858

Comment: using [lua-visual-debug](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug) [help you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UVnVc.png) to see better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting this in `gathered` inside `equation*` removes the whitespace:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{gathered}
    6x^2-30x+36=0\\
    6(x^2-5x+6)=0\\
    6(x-2)(x-3)=0\\
    x-2=0 \quad \text{or} \quad x-3=0\\
    x=2 \quad \text{or} \quad x=3
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The problem comes from the `varwidth` package, used by `standalone`.  Its minimal "documentation" in the header of `varwidth.sty` says:

> % AMSmath environments have not been tried, and undoubtedly fail.

A small test document demonstrates the behaviour we are seeing above:

[image: varwidth sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{15cm}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{gathered}
      6x^2-30x+36=0\\
      6(x^2-5x+6)=0
    \end{gathered}
  \end{equation*}
\end{varwidth}}

\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{15cm}
  \begin{gather*}
      6x^2-30x+36=0\\
      6(x^2-5x+6)=0
  \end{gather*}
\end{varwidth}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is it so any inside thoughts please ?

Comment: @texenthusiast See my updated answer

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for your brilliant insights.