# How to remove the white space on the left of gather* when using standalone class?

Tags: standalone

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% remove this line in  your production
\begin{gather*}
\int \sec^2(5 - 3x/4)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\int \frac{1}{\cos^2 (5 - 3x/4)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to remove the white space on the left of `gather*` when using `standalone` class?

Comment: Use `$\begin{gathered}...\end{gathered}$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine `gather`; it's just a one liner. You don't even have to set `\abovedisplayskip` to zero.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\renewenvironment{gather*}{$\gathered}{\endgathered$}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\int \sec^2(5 - 3x/4)\diff x\\
\int \frac{1}{\cos^2 (5 - \frac{3}{4}x)}\diff x
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Honestly I have known this solution but I want to insist on using `gather*`.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Aren't you using it? ;-)

Comment: It is a bit cumbersome if I have to add such an environment whenever I want to use `gather*` just for producing the tight output for accompanying my answer on `gather*` and its variants.

Comment: Don't forget `\!` before `***ed` math environment. :-)

Comment: It is a duplicate of [my own old question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115342/19356).