# Align long equations

Tags: align

I want to type the following equations by aligning them through the equal sign, but it seems to be too long:

```
\begin{align*}\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1)
&=& \prod_{l=0}^{l_0}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\times\prod_{l=l_1+1}^{n-1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\\
&=& \prod_{l=0}^{l_0}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^{-n}+1)\times\prod_{l=l_1+1}^{n-1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n)
\end{align*}
```

Someone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please always post a complete small document not just a fragment, it helps those trying to help and "too long" depends on the current page size, and fonts, which you haven't shown. `align` unlike `eqnarray` should just have `&=` not `&=&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another way:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{align*}
\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1)
&=\!
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        &\prod_{l=0}^{l_0}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)
        \prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1) \\
        &\rule{10cm}{0pt}\mathllap{\times\prod_{l=l_1+1}^{n-1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)}
    \end{aligned} \\
&=\!
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        &\prod_{l=0}^{l_0}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)
        \prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^{-n}+1) \\
        &\rule{10cm}{0pt}\mathllap{\times\prod_{l=l_1+1}^{n-1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)
        \prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n)}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `\!` is needed before `aligned` because of the issue discussed in [Why is there a \, space at the beginning of the “aligned” environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482/19356).

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `multlined` environment from the [mathtools package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1)&=
\begin{multlined}[t]
 \prod_{l=0}^{l_0}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)
 \prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1) \\       \times\prod_{l=l_1+1}^{n-1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)
\end{multlined} \\    &=
\begin{multlined}[t]
  \prod_{l=0}^{l_0}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)
  \prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^{-n}+1) \\         \times\prod_{l=l_1+1}^{n-1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)    
     \prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n)
\end{multlined}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You may want to change the location of the line breaks, depending on your font size, page width, etc.

[image: big equation]

Comment: Don't forget the `\!` before the multlined to cancel the mysterious extra space that you can see after the equals signs (there is a question about this somewhere, which I can't find).

Comment: For readability I don't think the `\times` items should be indented that excessively.

Comment: @RyanReich: The link  you want to find has been added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If it is too long you have to split the line in two pieces

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) &= \prod_{l=0}^{l_0}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\times\\
&\qquad\times\prod_{l=l_1+1}^{n-1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\\
&= \prod_{l=0}^{l_0}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^{-n}+1)\times\\
&\qquad\times\prod_{l=l_1+1}^{n-1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n+1)\prod_{l=l_0+1}^{l_1}(w_1(e^{\frac{(2l+1)\pi i}{n}})^n)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In western trasition the `\times` symbols are not duplicated, the one ending a line is not used.