# Remove extra space to the left of aligned environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

To typeset a collection of equations with alignment, I am using `align*` from `amsmath`.  Some of these equations have right-hand sides that have multiple lines that should be indented.  So far I am using a nested `aligned` environment and `\MoveEqLeft` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  x+y &= z+w \\
    a &= \begin{aligned}[t]
           \MoveEqLeft[0.5]
           b+c+d \\
           &+e+f \\
           &+g+h+i+j
         \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the `aligned` environment seems to introduce extra horizontal space to the left (and possibly on the right as well).   How can I eliminate the extra space from `aligned`?

I am open to other solutions that might avoid `aligned`, but I do not want to need to manually insert spaces to indent the lines.

Comment: This has already been discussed, I'll try finding the relevant question. But `\!\begin{aligned}` will remove the space. There's no space added at the end.

Comment: Here it is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/why-is-there-a-space-at-the-beginning-of-the-aligned-environment

Comment: @egreg Sorry I missed that!  Thanks for the pointer.