# How to remove indentation when using the aligned environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, amsmath

I want to align equations inside an enumeration, so I use the `aligned` environment and its `[t]` option to make the first equation appear on the same baseline as the item label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, leftmargin=*, label=\large\sffamily\bfseries \alph*)]
  \item $a = 1$
  \item
  $
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    a &= 1\\
    b &= 2\\
    c &= 3
  \end{aligned}
  $
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This works quite well, but I noticed that the `aligned` environment introduces a small indentation (I added the red line for better visualization):

[image: aligned indentation]

How can this be solved? Or is there an even better alternative to `aligned`?

Comment: Use `\!` before `\begin{aligned}`; the problem has already been discussed here: [Why is there a space at the beginning of the aligned environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/)

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I wasn't able to find the solution despite searching for nearly two days. :( Thank you very much!