# How to remove unnecessary space in flalign* environment

Tags: line-breaking, align, enumerate

This is the first time I've ever used TeX and I'm super confused as to why this is happening. When I used the `flalign*` environment within the `enumerate` environment, it leaves line break after the item number 2., when I'd really like to have the equation begin on the same line as number 2., as it does with number 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\date{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}


\begin{document}
\textbf{Question 3.6.}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$
\item\begin{flalign*}
\mathcal{P}\Big(\mathcal{P}\big(\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\big)\Big)&=\mathcal{P}\Big(\mathcal{P}\big(\{\emptyset\}\big)\Big)&\\
\mathcal{P}\big(\{\emptyset\}\big)&=\big\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\big\}\\
\mathcal{P}\Big(\mathcal{P}\big(\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\big)\Big)&=\mathcal{P}\big(\big\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\big\}\big)\\
&=\Big\{\emptyset , \{\emptyset\},\big\{\{\emptyset\}\big\}, \big\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\big\}\Big\}
\end{flalign*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Also, you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: similar: questions 46645 and 98397 using `aligned` within "inline" math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some lazy way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\date{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}


\begin{document}
\textbf{Question 3.6.}
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}           %% new
\item $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$
\item \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}      %% new
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
 \begin{flalign*}
\mathcal{P}\Big(\mathcal{P}\big(\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\big)\Big)&=\mathcal{P}\Big(\mathcal{P}\big(\{\emptyset\}\big)\Big)&\\
\mathcal{P}\big(\{\emptyset\}\big)&=\big\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\big\}\\
\mathcal{P}\Big(\mathcal{P}\big(\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\big)\Big)&=\mathcal{P}\big(\big\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\big\}\big)\\
&=\Big\{\emptyset , \{\emptyset\},\big\{\{\emptyset\}\big\}, \big\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\big\}\Big\}
\end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}                            %% new
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong tool: what you need is `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
\textbf{Question 3.6.}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$
\item $\!\begin{aligned}[t]
  \mathcal{P}\Bigl(\mathcal{P}\bigl(\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\bigr)\Bigr)&=
    \mathcal{P}\Bigl(\mathcal{P}\bigl(\{\emptyset\}\bigr)\Bigr)&\\
  \mathcal{P}\bigl(\{\emptyset\}\bigr)&=
    \bigl\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\bigr\}\\
  \mathcal{P}\Bigl(\mathcal{P}\bigl(\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\bigr)\Bigr)&=
    \mathcal{P}\bigl(\bigl\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\bigr\}\bigr)\\
  &=\Big\{\emptyset , \{\emptyset\},\bigl\{\{\emptyset\}\bigr\}, 
    \bigl\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\bigr\}\Big\}
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The `\!` before `\begin{aligned}[t]` has been discussed in [Why is there a \, space at the beginning of the "aligned" environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/why-is-there-a-space-at-the-beginning-of-the-aligned-environment)

[image]

Note that `\big` and `\Big` are wrong and you should use `\bigl` or `\Bigl` for the opening fences and `\bigr` or `\Bigr` for the closing ones.