# Multlined in align enviromnent: alignment of = and equation numbering

Tags: amsmath, mathtools, multline

I'm using the `multlined` environment inside an `align` environment and want have the `=` aligned at the top and the equation numbering at the bottom. Is this possible?

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
y &= a+b+c \\
&= \begin{multlined}[t]
a+b+ \\
c
\end{multlined}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
y &= a+b+c \\
&= \begin{multlined}[b]
a+b+ \\
c
\end{multlined}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to place the `=` inside `multlined`; in order to get alignment, though, a `\!` is necessary (`multlined` does the same as `aligned` and `gathered` that add `\,` at their left border).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
y &= a+b+c \\
  &  \!\begin{multlined}[b]
     = a+b+{} \\
          c
     \end{multlined}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! also for the comment about the negative spacing. Can you explain to me why the `{}` is needed? And one off-topic question: is it more common to place the last operator in the first or in the second line? Meaning: `a+b+\\c` or `a+b\\+c` ?

Comment: @bonanza The `{}` is necessary to get correct spacing of `+`: a binary operator needs to have operands on both sides. You can compare with your output and see that `b` and `+` are next to each other without any space. Whether having the operand on the top or bottom line is a stylistic decision; in general I prefer to have it at the end of the top line, which makes clearer that the formula is not finished.

Comment: for more information about the `{}` see [Why is there a `\,` space at the beginning of the “`aligned`” environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482/579)

Comment: @egreg Is there an easy solution for the case when the first line (the one with $y$) spans two lines?

Comment: @LucaCiti Can't you do the same?

Comment: @egreg Unless I'm missing something obvious, you can't get the eq number to have any vertical alignment other than to the top row, otherwise $y$ too will have the wrong alignment.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to have $&y=$ too inside the `multlined` and then add a `&\phantom{y}=` to the other equations.

Comment: @LucaCiti Please, make a new question with an example.

Comment: @egerg I have made a new question (an provided my tentative answer) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388518/multlined-in-align-enviromnent-alignment-of-rhs-and-equation-numbering).