# Multlined in align enviromnent: alignment of "RHS =" and equation numbering

Tags: numbering, align, multline

I'm using `multlined` (from `mathtools`) inside `align` to show a chain of equivalences between expressions, some of which may not fit in a line. I would like to align the equation numbering at the bottom (or centre) of the lines that are part of the same expression. **Edited**: Because I have other `multline` elsewhere, for consistency, I would like the broken lines to be aligned as if they were standalone `multline` equations, i.e. first line left, middle lines centre, last line right.

While an answer to [Multlined in align enviromnent: alignment of = and equation numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180547/multlined-in-align-enviromnent-alignment-of-and-equation-numbering) provides a solution for the lines after the first one, that solution does not work for the first line because the RHS of the first equality is misaligned.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=7.00cm, height=17.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        y &  \begin{multlined}[b]
        = a+b+{} \\
        c+d+{} \\
        e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l
        \end{multlined} \\
        &= a+b+c
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

The only solution that I found involves the use of `phantom` and is a bit hacky. I wonder if a better solution (**Edited**: which does not require phantoms or manual spacing) exists.

Comment: Why not use `\begin{multlined}[t]` instead of `c`?

Comment: @Aditya That would also move the equation number to the top, while I would like it to be centred.

Comment: from the appearance of the example, it's not really clear what you would want the expression to look like if the last line was quite a bit longer than either the first or middle lines.  if you would make that clear, i'll try to come up with something that works there.  also, i thin you mentioned in a comment that you preferred that the positioning would be automatic, and not require either manual spacing or phantoms.  that is best also mentioned in the question.

Comment: You can put the tag on any line by using the command `\taghere` from John Kormylo's answer to my question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299988/100861 (and if you don't want the tag to be exactly on a line, then you can move it up or down using the optional argument of that command.)

Comment: @wea0 Thanks for linking to that question, it has a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 5):

try this, using  `\split` within the `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
      \begin{split}
        y &= a+b+{} \\
          &\qquad c+d+e
      \end{split} \\
        &= a+b+c
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- very gracious, sir!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for posting this solution. This was my first attempt but it requires manual alignment of the lines. I wanted the broken lines to be aligned as if they were standalone `multline` equations, i.e. first line left, middle lines centre, last line right.

Comment: @LucaCiti - The example code you provided only mentioned two lines in the `multlined` environment. It would have been helpful if you'd mentioned up front that the environment might contain 3 or more lines.

Comment: @Mico Good, point. I have edited the question as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves changing the alignment point of `align` to the beginning of the line (rather than at the equal sign) and then using a `phantom` to add an empty space corresponding to the RHS to all the subsequent lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=7.00cm, height=11.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        &\begin{multlined}[b]
        y = a+b+{} \\
        \phantom{y=}c+d+{}\\
        \phantom{y=}e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l
        \end{multlined} \\
        &\phantom{y} = a+b+c
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

This gives the desired behaviour (Eqs 1 and 2 in the question).

As I try to use phantoms as last resort, I wonder if someone can come up with a better solution.