# Multlined in align environment: letter before alignment point

Tags: align, amsmath, mathtools, multline

I have two equations, one of which is very long. I would like to have a single alignment, at the `=` sign. At the same time, I would like to split the long equation into multiple lines. I have tried to use `multlined`, but I am not able to obtain the desired result.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
F &= a + b\\
G &= \begin{multlined}[b](c + d\\
    {} + e + f + g + h)
    \end{multlined}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

It typesets as shown below:

[image]

I am aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180547/multlined-in-align-enviromnent-alignment-of-and-equation-numbering), yet the presence of `G` before the alignment point makes its solution not directly applicable to my case.

Comment: What happens if you replace `[b]` with `[t]`?

Comment: The `aligned`, `gathered`, `multlined` etc environments take an optional argument to let users specify the vertical alignment relative to the surrounding material. These options are `t` (top), `c` (center -- the default), and `b` (bottom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis) pointed out, just change `[b]` with `[t]` in the `multlined` environment. Adding another line does not break anything.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    F &= a + b\\
    G &= \begin{multlined}[t]
            (c + d              \\
            {} + e + f + g + h)
        \end{multlined} \\
    H &= i + j + k
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: result]