# Not getting alignment that I want in an alignat environment

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

In the following display, `$+ \frac{1}{4!}$` in the third line of the `alignat` environment should be aligned directly below `$+ \frac{1}{2!}$` in the second line.  Depending on the spacing in the corrected display, I may want to have `$+ \frac{1}{n!}$` aligned directly below `$+ \frac{1}{4!}$`.  Why does my code not give me this alignment?  How do I get the alignment that I want?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\em The sequence}
\begin{equation*}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}
\end{equation*}
{\em is bounded between $2$ and $2.75$.}
\vskip0.2in

\noindent $a_{1} = 2$, and since the given sequence is an increasing sequence, $a_{n} > 2$ for every integer $n > 1$. According to the Binomial Theorem,
\allowdisplaybreaks{
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} &= 1 + \binom{n}{1} \frac{1}{n} + \binom{n}{2} \frac{1}{n^{2}} + \binom{n}{3} \frac{1}{n^{3}} + \ldots
+ \binom{n}{n} \frac{1}{n^{n}} \\
&= 1 + 1 &&+ \frac{1}{2!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \\
&&&+ \frac{1}{4!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{3}{n}\right) + \ldots \\
&&&+ \frac{1}{n!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{n - 1}{n}\right) \\
&< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n!} \\
&= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3!} + \frac{2}{4!} + \ldots + \frac{2}{n!}\right) \\
&< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^{2}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\right) \\
&< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^{2}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{3^{n-2}} + \frac{1}{3^{n-1}} + \frac{1}{3^{n}} + \ldots \right) \\
&< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \\
&= 2 + \frac{3}{4} . \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{alignat*}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's necessary to set up and fine-tune an `alignat*` environment. A basic `align*` environment, coupled with two `\phantom` statement, suffices.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\noindent 
{\em The sequence
\begin{equation*}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}
\end{equation*}
is bounded between $2$ and $2.75$.}

\vskip0.2in

\noindent $a_{1} = 2$, and since the given sequence is an increasing 
sequence, $a_{n} > 2$ for every integer $n > 1$. According to the Binomial 
Theorem,
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} &= 1 + \binom{n}{1} \frac{1}{n} + 
  \binom{n}{2} \frac{1}{n^{2}} + \binom{n}{3} \frac{1}{n^{3}} + \dots
  + \binom{n}{n} \frac{1}{n^{n}} \\
&= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(1 - 
  \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \\
&\phantom{{}= 1 + 1}{}+ \frac{1}{4!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - 
  \frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{3}{n}\right) + \dotsb \\
&\phantom{{}= 1 + 1}{}+ \frac{1}{n!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - 
  \frac{2}{n}\right) \dotsb \left(1 - \frac{n - 1}{n}\right) \\
&< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \dots + \frac{1}{n!} \\
&= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3!} + \frac{2}{4!} + 
  \dots + \frac{2}{n!}\right) \\
&< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^{2}} + 
  \dots + \frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\right) \\
&< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^{2}} + 
\dots + \frac{1}{3^{n-2}} + \frac{1}{3^{n-1}} + \frac{1}{3^{n}} + \dotsb 
  \right) \\
&< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \\
&= 2 + \frac{3}{4} \,. \quad \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep.  I had the proper alignment with an `align` environment and `\hphantom` commands.  I want to know how to do it with an `alignat` environment.  (I think not having both alignments set in the first line is leading to the misalignment ... but I don't know why that is happening!)

Comment: @user74973 - The problem you described in your posting arises because there's no second alignment point in the first and the final row of the ten-row expression. Short of re-writing the first and last rows in some major ways, I see no way how an `alignat*` environment might be used here.

Comment: Either I didn't know that about the `alignat` environment or I forgot about it - one needs to maintain all alignment marks in every line of an `alignat` environment.  Thanks.

Comment: since `amsart` is being used, i think `\qedhere` would be a good thing, with the symbol being changed if desired.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for pointing out the availability of the `\qedhere` macro. Let's see if the OP weighs in and expresses a view on the preferred appearance of the QED symbol.

Comment: @Mico   Coincidentally, I am currently referring to an analysis textbook that uses `\qedhere`.  I have seen more and more textbooks using this symbol, too.  I guess that I prefer the symbol that I have been using because it is customary for me.  Objectively, it is more noticeable than the symbol printed using `\qedhere`.

Answer (score 2):

Nest `aligned` in an `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheorem*{statement}{Statement}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{statement}
The sequence
\begin{equation*}
a_{n}=\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}
\end{equation*}
is bounded between $2$ and $2.75$.
\end{statement}

\begin{proof}
We have $a_{1} = 2$ and, since the given sequence is an increasing sequence, $a_{n} > 2$ 
for every integer $n > 1$. According to the Binomial Theorem,
\begin{align*}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} 
  &= 1 + \binom{n}{1} \frac{1}{n} + \binom{n}{2} \frac{1}{n^{2}} + \binom{n}{3} \frac{1}{n^{3}} + \dots
     + \binom{n}{n} \frac{1}{n^{n}} \\
  &= \!\begin{aligned}[t]
     1 + 1 &+ \frac{1}{2!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)
            + \frac{1}{3!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \\
           &+ \frac{1}{4!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 
            - \frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{3}{n}\right) + \dotsb \\
           &+ \frac{1}{n!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \dots
                \left(1 - \frac{n - 1}{n}\right)
     \end{aligned}\\
  &< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n!} \\
  &= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3!} + \frac{2}{4!} + \dots + \frac{2}{n!}\right) \\
  &< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^{2}} + \dots
       + \frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\right) \\
  &< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^{2}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{3^{n-2}}
       + \frac{1}{3^{n-1}} + \frac{1}{3^{n}} + \ldots \right) \\
  &< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \\
  &= 2 + \frac{3}{4} .\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\allowdisplaybreaks` is a declaration and not a command with argument. It should be issued in the preamble and removed for the final version of the document, where suitable `\displaybreak` commands should be added at the desired spots.

Comment: This is some nice code.  Why do you have ` \!` before the `aligned` environment?  Is there an erroneous `small space` that `LaTeX` puts before such environments, and a `small negative space` is needed to cancel the `small space`?  Does the option `t` put the `aligned` environment flush to the bottom of the first line of the `align` environment?

Comment: @user74973 The `\!` has been discussed in [Why is there a space at the beginning of the `aligned` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/). The `[t]` is to get `aligned` into using the top row for the vertical positioning.

Comment: I tried replacing `allowdisplaybreaks` with `displaybreak`.  I get an error.  Do I need a package in the preamble?

Comment: @user74973 `\displaybreak` should go in the row of `align` you want a break after.

Comment: I get an error compiling your code:  "Command `\!` invalid in math mode on line 102.  ! Argument of `\begin` has an extra `}`."  Do I need some additional package in my preamble to use an `aligned` environment?

Comment: @user74973 Sorry, but I just pasted the code I wrote for getting the shown output. `Command \! invalid in math mode` means you (or some package you're using) have redefined it.

Comment: I had `\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}` in my preamble to define the arc command.  I don't need it in this file.  I would prefer to keep it, though.  What is an equivalent command for `\!`?  Is it `\hspace{- blah}`?

Comment: @user74973 `\usepackage[safe]{tipa}` doesn't redefine `\|`, `\:`, `\;`, `\!`; since the package provides substitutes for these, it's better doing so when math is used in the document. I'm not sure what “arc command” you're referring to, but probably it can be defined without `tipa`.

Comment: I just saw that the `\negthinspace` command is abbreviated by `\!`.  So, I can use `\negthinspace` to avoid another package like `tipa` from redefining it.  (`\negthinspace` is equal to 1/6 of a `quad`.)

Comment: @user74973 No, `\negthinspace` is for use in text, not in math. You'll experience other problems without the `safe` option to `tipa`, when you have math in your document.

Comment: Rats!  Should I just use `\usepackage[safe]{tipa}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble?

Comment: @user74973 Yes. But maybe you can make a new question about the “arc command”.

Comment: These are the declarations that I have in my preamble to have `TikZ` draw the arc symbol above two or three letters indicating an arc of a circle.  `\usepackage{graphicx}`, `usepackage{tipa}`,  `\newcommand{\arc}[1] {%
  \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%
  \ooalign{\resizebox{\wd9}{\height}{\texttoptiebar{\phantom{A}}}\cr#1}}`.  I found them on `tex.stackexchange`.

Comment: @user74973 I added a different answer that avoids the dependency on `tipa` (and fixes the buggy solution you were using).

Comment: Did you add a different answer?  I can also avoid `tipa` from redefining `\!` by replacing `\!` with a `\hspace{}` command with  an appropriate value for the width.  Do you know what that is in math mode?

Comment: @user74973 The answer was to the question about `\arc`