# How to align equations cases environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, cases

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{cases}
   Af &=g \quad \text{if} \ c,\\
   f&=0 \quad \text{if} \ d.
\end{cases}$
\end{document}
```

gives
[image]

How to align the two f's vertically (so that they are both in the same distance from the '=' sign)?

Comment: I don't see the reason for `\quad` there. In the second line, write `\phantom{A}f` to get the `f`s aligned.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, that is what I wanted. But is there not any other solution, like specifying the alignment requirements in the options of 'cases'?

Comment: Ah, I see, in `{cases}`, the `&` is there to separate columns, not before the equal.

Comment: @Manuel Sorry, I don't get what you mean and how it can help me.

Comment: You are not supposed to write `&=` inside a `{cases}` environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `aligned` instead of `cases`.  If you wonder, why there is `\!` after `\left\{`, see [Why is there a \, space at the beginning of the “aligned” environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/why-is-there-a-space-at-the-beginning-of-the-aligned-environment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
   Af &=g && \text{if} \ c,\\
   f &=0 && \text{if} \ d.
\end{aligned}\right.$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{cases}
    Af=g & \text{if} \ c, \\
    \phantom{A}f = 0 & \text{if} \ d.
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Altough I tend to prefer

```
\begin{cases*}
  Af=g & if $c$, \\
  \phantom{A}f = 0 & if $d$.
\end{cases*}
```