# Spacing problem with aligned nested in an align environement

Tags: spacing, align

This minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A 
  &\leq
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      &\int \text{first part of a long expression}
      \\& \times \text{second part of the long expression}
    \end{aligned}
  \\&\leq \int \text{shorther expression}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: there is too much space before the first integral]

The two integral signs are not aligned because there is too much space before the first ones (or equivalently, before the aligned environment).

> How can I get the correct horizontal space before the first integral sign?

Comment: I don't get it. I guess that would just create more space... which is not what I want.

Comment: no. I just tested it. They are both shifted to the right but don't get aligned.

Comment: There is a "bug" in aligned,  whenever you  what to use it like this remember to use `\! \begin{aligned}....` this removes the added space in front of `aligned`

Comment: @daleif Good to know. Adding `\!` solved the problem.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Comment: @daleif oups! Sorry! I correct what I just wrote: Adding `\!` *seemed* to solve the problem... It made it more aligned but not completely. This is really a small detail, but there is still a difference.

Comment: It seems to be because you start the lines with `&\int` add `\!` before the `&` inside `aligned` or move (if space) `&` after `\int`

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/why-is-there-a-space-at-the-beginning-of-the-aligned-environment?s=1|0.0000

Comment: If you have `&\int` in the `aligned` part, remember that `\int` is an operator and that `amsmath` inserts `{}` after `&`, so you get a thin space in front of the operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general whenever `aligned` is used when there is "something" is front for it to align with, then always use

```
\! \begin{aligned} ....
```

This removes the spacing that is inserted at the start of `aligned`

Edit: there seems to be another issue at play, if the contents of `aligned` starts with `&` then there is also spacing issues. The problem and a fix can be seen in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A
  &\leq\rlap{\raisebox{-7em}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{0.4pt}{8em}}} 
  \!
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    &\int
  \end{aligned}
  \\
  &\leq
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
    \! &\int
  \end{aligned}
  \\
  &\leq \int
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be `&\!\int`; there is an implicit `{}` after `&`, which makes TeX insert a thin space between the empty ordinary atom and the operator atom.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `aligned`, in this case, by using `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
A&\leq \int \text{first part of a long expression} \\
 & \qquad\times \text{second part of the long expression}
\end{split}
\\
&\leq \int \text{shorther expression}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The alternative with `aligned` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A&\leq
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &\!\int \text{first part of a long expression} \\
    &\quad\times \text{second part of the long expression}
  \end{aligned}
\\
&\leq \int \text{shorther expression}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

One `\!` is necessary in front of `aligned`, see [Why is there a \, space at the beginning of the "aligned" environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/); another one is needed between `&` and `\int`, because after `&` there is an implicit `{}` that forces a thin spaces between it and `\int`, which is an operator atom.

[image]