# How to code a terraced math formula in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mathtools

How to code a terraced math formula in Latex, such as the following picture? What I really need is to align "C" with the first "+" in second line, "F" with the first "+" in third line.

[image]

Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested `aligned` environments for that.  (For an explanation of the `\!` read [Why is there a \, space at the beginning of the “aligned” environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A = B \{ & C + D \\
  &\!\begin{aligned}[t]
    {} + E [ & F + G \\
    & + H ( I + J) ] \}
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But maybe you are rather looking for `multline`.  It’ll left-align the first line, right-align the last line and center all lines in between.  In this case it looks very awkward because the lines are so short.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
  A = B \{ C + D \\
  + E [ F + G \\
  + H ( I + J) ] \}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! It's exactly what I need! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use proper nesting of environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A = B \{ & C + D \\
& \negmedspace +
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
    E[ & F + G \\
    & \negmedspace + H(I+J)]\}
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

With `\negmedspace` we remove the space before the `+` (which has to be inserted or the one after it would disappear).

[image]