# Vertical spacing inside mathtools's multlined

Tags: mathtools, multline

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
  f(1) &= g(1) + g(2) + g(3) \\
  f(1) &= g(1) + g(2) + g(3) \\
  f(1) &= \!\begin{multlined}[t]g(1) + g(2) + g(3) + g(1) + g(2) + g(3)\\
          g(1) + g(2) + g(3) + g(1) + g(2) + g(3) 
          \end{multlined}
          \\
  f(1) &= g(1) + g(2) + g(3) \\
  f(1) &= g(1) + g(2) + g(3) 
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

produces [image: output]

I looked in the mathtools's code and could not see how to set things up so that the vertical spacing between `multlined` lines is exactly the same as between other `amsmath` constructs. I know I can say `\\[10pt]` to adjust one instance, but I'd like to set this up once and for all for all `multlined`s in the whole document.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know either, but I think it is better for an easy  understanding of the equations: a multlined environment semantically corresponds to a block that one  has to split because there's not enough horizontal space, so the corresponding lines do not have the same status as the other lines, individually.

Comment: I understand that is the intention, but I find it more distracting than helpful —and the lines look way too cramped, in my opinion. I prefer to have the horizontal spacing as a cue of logical grouping in this situation.

Comment: In this case, I believe `aligned`  has the usual spacing, and you can align this group by the right side, for instance.

Comment: That works if the multlined has only two lines, and only then. It usually doesn't.

Comment: It is known that `multlined` has certain spacing issues that are not that easy to point point. I hardly ever use any of the multlined stuff and they end up having a very inconsistent look.

Answer (score 4):

This might help

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\def\MT_mult_invisible_line: {
  \crcr
  \global\MH_set_boolean_F:n {mult_firstline}
  \hbox to \l_MT_multwidth_dim{}\crcr
  \noalign{
    \vskip-\baselineskip 
    %\vskip-\jot 
    \vskip-\normallineskip
  }
}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
```

Not quite sure why `\jot` was added in the first place, probably because of `spreadlines`.

Comment: Just to nag: Could the `\!` spacing issue be removed from `mathtools`, now that `amsmath` got rid of it? Or has it already happened and I didn't notice it?

Comment: @campa it is on my top list. But did amsmath actually got rid of it for aligned? I had not noticed

Comment: [Yep, see here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353026/82917)

Comment: @campa good, though, not sure if the hspace issue in `multline` is the same. I'll have a look before the next release

Comment: @campa turns out to be a walk in the park to fix. Until release you can use this (requires `etoolbox`): `\makeatletter
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\ifpatchable{\MT_mult_internal:n}{%
  \MH_if_boolean:nF {outer_mult}{\null\,}%
}{
 \patchcmd{\MT_mult_internal:n}{% 
   \MH_if_boolean:nF {outer_mult}{\null\,}%
 }{%
   \MH_if_boolean:nF {outer_mult}{\alignedspace@left}%
 }{
   \typeout{patched}
 }{
   \typeout{patch failed}
 }
}{\typeout{no, not patchable}}

\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother`

Answer (score 2):

Here, I substituted the `multilined` with a `\Longunderstack`, where you can set the interline baselineskip explicitly with `\setstackgap{L}{...}`.  I loaded `tabstackengine` (instead of `stackengine`), in case you wanted to employ additional tabbing features in your stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
  f(1) &= g(1) + g(2) + g(3) \\
  f(1) &= g(1) + g(2) + g(3) \\
  f(1) &= \Longunderstack[l]{ g(1) + g(2) + g(3) + g(1) + g(2) + g(3)\\
          \quad g(1) + g(2) + g(3) + g(1) + g(2) + g(3) 
          }
          \\
  f(1) &= g(1) + g(2) + g(3) \\
  f(1) &= g(1) + g(2) + g(3) 
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]